# Batch- Using acquired file names with spaces

Tags: file, batch-file

In my program, I pull file names from a bunch of folders, and some of them have spaces. I've tried setting them in quotes. I've tried putting set in quotes. I've tried delayed expansion. I've tried everything I can find so far.

The relevant code as it currently is:

```
SET "FTPFOLDER=C:\temp"


REM THIS GOES THROUGH THE FILE SYSTEM INITIALLY.
pause
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b "%FTPFOLDER%"') do (call :Search "%%f") 
pause

REM GOES THRU EACH OF THE FILES IN EACH OF THE FOLDERS. IF THE FILE READ IS A FOLDER, IT GOES SEARCHES DEEPER INTO THE FOLDER.

:Search
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%g in ('dir /b "%FTPFOLDER%\%~1"') do (if exist "%FTPFOLDER%\%~1\%%g\*" (
set nsearch =%~1\%%g
call :Search !nsearch!
)  else (
set filedir = %FTPFOLDER%\%~1\%%g\
set filename = %%~ng
call :checkSize  !filedir!, !filename!
)
)
pause
EXIT /B 0

REM CHECKS IF ZERO 
:checkSize
pause
set file="%~1"
@echo %file%
for /f "usebackq" %%h in ('%file%') do (set size=%%~zh)
if %size% EQU 0 (call :Rename "%file%", %~2)
pause
EXIT /B 0

REM - RENAMES FILE TO .EMPTY
:Rename
pause
ren %~1 %~2.empty
pause
EXIT /B 0
```

I have honestly tried everything I've seen and none of it has worked. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: Literally I learned nothing new about what is wrong from that, except that my variables aren't working the way they are supposed to, which I already knew

Comment: Well you could start by telling us where it is going wrong.

Comment: It stops running when it tries to call checkSize.

Comment: What do you mean it stops running?

Comment: The program closes as if it finished running. It also doesn't echo the variables if I try to make it.

Comment: Why have you got commas between your call parameters?

Comment: Because it helps it look more organized to me. It shouldn't effect how the code runs as far as I know because I've done things before with commas between parameters.

Comment: Don't put spaces around the `=` in a `set` assignment, because they become part of the variable name and value otherwise!

Comment: Commas can indicate that you aren't providing a parameter. AFAIK only `copy` takes note of it (it turns `copy` into a `touch` command - `copy /b file1,,`). But that doesn't mean other commands don't. CMD has a wide list of characters that it considers delimiters, but most programs are more restrictive. See `schtasks/?` and `schtasks/query/?` v's `schtasks/query /?`. The first delimiter is `/` found by command. Everything after that is passed to the program which usually only take spaces as a delimiter..

Comment: @aschipfl alright thanks! I didn't even think about that. I'm used to being able to do that sort of thing!

Comment: @Noodles I've never had any problems using commas before. I'll remove them if I still have problems!

Comment: @Noodles, if you are referring to the commas in the `call` command lines, they are not a problem as `cmd` interpretes them as token separators, like also _SPACE_, _TAB_, `;` and `=`...

Comment: Only the first one. Subsequent ones aren't passed by CMD but by program's runtimes. They tend to expect spaces.

Comment: So I got the function checkSize to run, but when it tries to get the file size, it doesn't return anything. I shouldn't need to enable delayed expansion as it worked fine in an earlier version of the program. Any ideas?

Comment: So I also tried with delayed expansion and it didn't make a difference, so I'm once again lost.

Comment: I somehow got it to work perfectly and I don't really know how, so if either of you want to see my code at some point to tell me exactly what occurred, just let me know